# Oracle SOA BPEL 12c authentication credentials pass through

Tags: soa, oracle12c, composite, bpel, soa-suite

I am trying to pass-through Basic http authentication credentials received from consumer of Composite (through Service endpoint) to other webservice invoked by Composite (through reference endpoint).

Can someone please provide me details required for this setup.

I am able to do it in Oracle Service Bus (OSB) using Service Account (as pass through resource type). But unable to do it using SOA Composite (BPEL).

Below link has raised similar question but unfortunately details of the solution was not mentioned

[Bpel 12c - Call webservices with basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081479/bpel-12c-call-webservices-with-basic-authentication)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please update your question with an example, and explain what is not working.

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks for your response. I have tried with OSB and able to do it. Also I have tried with custom http headers with SOA composite and that is working fine. 

Below is what I am trying to do 

SOA Consumer -> SOA Composite -> target service.     

When SOA consumer invokes SOA Composite and passes HTTP authentication credentials for Basic HTTP Authentication ( Eg: user1/user1password), SOA Composite should authenticate user1 and pass same HTTP Authentication credentials to target service so that Target service can again authenticate user1

Comment: Hi Phil, I hope you saw my latest update. Can you please share if you have any inputs for me.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have experience with this. I was only commenting to help you provide enough information from others who might be able to help. I would suggest editing your original question with details from your comment. It makes things easier for everybody to read and understand.