# how to pass dynamic variable in basic authentication in soa 12c?

Tags: soap, basic-authentication, soa, bpel

Username and Password in received in body from source xml.

```
<UsernameToken>
<Username>Dtest</Username>
<Password>test@123</Password>
</UsernameToken>
```

I have stored the same in variable in bpel.

```
 <assign name="Assign_Authentication">
      <copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes" bpelx:insertMissingToData="yes">
        <from>$receiveInput_makepayment_InputVariable.RequestPG/ns3:UserNameToken/ns3:Username</from>
        <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$usernameVar</to>
      </copy>
      <copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes" bpelx:insertMissingToData="yes">
        <from>$receiveInput_makepayment_InputVariable.RequestPG/ns3:UserNameToken/ns3:Password</from>
        <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$passwordVar</to>
      </copy>
    </assign>
```

Now, issue is i have to send the variables as **basic authentication to target soap service**.

Please can someone guide me how to achieve the same.

Comment: I tried following the below link, but after cfgplan.xml what needs to be done to pass the value dynamically to the target as basic authentication isnt mentioned.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081479/bpel-12c-call-webservices-with-basic-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Adding below in Invoke Activity worked, passing the variables in the below properties:

```
<bpelx:toProperties>
          <bpelx:toProperty name="javax.xml.ws.security.auth.username" variable="usernameVar"/>
          <bpelx:toProperty name="javax.xml.ws.security.auth.password" variable="passwordVar"/>
        </bpelx:toProperties>
```